# How to avoid ignoring actions on widgets before executing a nested function?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

**The goal is to first perform actions on widgets (create Button_1 and remove Button_2) and only then enable speech recognition func.**

I tried 2 options.

Using *asyncio,* but actions with the buttons occur only after completion of `voiceRecognition` execution:

```
def callSomeFunc(self, event):
    asyncio.run(someFunc(voiceRecognition))

async def someFunc(self, event):
    #creates Button_1
    #deletes config.Button_2 (from another func)

    await event()

def voiceRecognition(self): 
        r = sr.Recognizer() 
        chekVar = 1 

        while chekVar == 1: 
            with sr.Microphone() as sourse:     
                    audio = r.listen(sourse) 
                    recognizedQuery = r.recognize_google(audio) 
                    if recognizedQuery== 'Stop': 
                        chekVar = 0
```

Using *concurrent.futures,* but actions with the buttons occur only after completion of `voiceRecognition` execution:

```
def callSomeFunc(self, event):
    self.someFunc()

def someFunc(self, event):
    #creates config.Button_1
    #deletes config.Button_2 (from another func)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        fut = executor.submit(voiceRecognition)

def voiceRecognition(self): 
    r = sr.Recognizer() 
    chekVar = 1 

    while chekVar == 1: 
        with sr.Microphone() as sourse:     
                audio = r.listen(sourse) 
                recognizedQuery = r.recognize_google(audio) 
                if recognizedQuery== 'Stop': 
                    chekVar = 0
```

Am I taking the right approach? The most important thing is that actions on widgets should happen first. Help me figure out how to do this, please. Thanks.